# Multiple file upload with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to upload multiple files with progress bars to show how much of the file has been uploaded. For some reason the files are not being uploaded and the progress bars only work for one upload. Please help me alter the code to work.

```js
$('.btnUpload').click(function(){
    //submit all form
    $('form').submit();
});
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);

    uploadImage($form);

});

function uploadImage($form){
    alert("in");
    $form.find('.progress-bar')
    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //progress event...
    request.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){
        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100);
        $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent+'%').html(percent+'%');
    });

    //progress completed load event
    request.addEventListener('load',function(e){
        $form.find('.progress-bar').html('upload completed....');
    });

    request.open('post', 'upload.php');
    request.send(formdata);

    $form.on('click','.cancel',function(){
        request.abort();

        $form.find('.progress-bar')
            .html('upload aborted...');
    });

}/*
function uploadFile(){
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#gallery").html(data);
                },
                xhrFields: {
                    // add listener to XMLHTTPRequest object directly for progress (jquery doesn't have this yet)
                    onprogress: function (progress) {
                        // calculate upload progress
                        var percentage = Math.floor((progress.total / progress.totalSize) * 100);
                        // log upload progress to console
                        console.log('progress', percentage);
                        if (percentage === 100) {
                            console.log('DONE!');
                        }
                    }
                },
                processData:false,

                error: function(){}
            });
        }));
    });
}*/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP AJAX Multiple Image Upload</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <SCRIPT SRC="upload.js"></SCRIPT>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="gallery-bg">
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post">
<div id="gallery">No Images in Gallery</div>
<div id="uploadFormLayer">
<p class="txt-subtitle">Upload Multiple Image:</p>
<p><input name="userImage[]" type="file" class="inputFile" /><p>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%"></div>
        </div>

<p><input name="userImage[]" type="file" class="inputFile" /><p>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;">
        </div>
    </div>
<p><input name="userImage[]" type="file" class="inputFile" /><p>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;">
        </div>
    </div>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnUpload"  /></p>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't use ready() mid-ajax callback, just run the code

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but perhaps a solution to your problem.

What you posted sends the files to the server, but once they get there they are kept in a sandbox -- they must be "handled" once they get there or they won't be stored. Therefore, you must write a processor app in your back-end language (PHP or ASP.Net or etc.) to process the files (validate them, move them to the folder they are supposed to be in, etc.).

If your back-end is PHP, would you consider switching to Ravishanker Kusuma's [jQuery Upload File Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)? I've tried a bunch of file upload plugins and found Ravi's the best. Use it in all my projects. Try his example (link above) - it's dead simple.

1) Include the Hayageek scripts

2) Add a div, which becomes the dynamic upload button/fields

```
<div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>
```

3) Add this jQuery code:

```
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url:"name_of_your_php_file_that_receives_the_files.php",
    fileName:"myfile" //you will use this varname in the php file
});
```

That PHP file will look something like this:

```
<?php
    $output_dir = "uploads/";
    if(isset($_FILES["myfile"])) {
        $ret = array();

        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) {
            //just one file
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
            $ret[]= $fileName;
        }
        else  //Multiple files, file[]
        {
          $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
          for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
          {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
            $ret[]= $fileName;
          }

        }
        echo json_encode($ret);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I do have php script that sends the image to the folder.
But thanks will try that

Comment: I managed to upload all the file but the progress bars only listen for one upload.

Comment: Please see my answer for the multiple progress bars http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721400/ajax-upload-showing-progress-of-only-file-in-multiple-file-uploads/31722317#31722317